# GCP gsutil set cors: No such file or directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage

I've created a bucket and uploaded the cors.json file to it to set the bucket's cors policy. But when I run the command:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://my_bucket
```

All I receive back is the message: No such file or directory.

Even when I run the command

```
gsutil ls gs://my_bucket
```

I get the file back:

```
gs://my_bucket/cors.json
```

Can someone help me to understand why the command `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://my_bucket` is finding my file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I've created the `cors.json` file within the bucket, while it needed to be outside of it. So I just upload the file to the current path in the terminal and it worked fine.

Google's documentation says only to create a file, I think it should be more explicit.